# Need guidance on multiple levels of aggregation in a same column in SQL

Tags: sql, function, logic

I am reframing my question to simplify the requirements.

In our table, we have 4 columns, i.e. row_id, row_name, value, row_aggregate_into. row_aggregate_into will contain reference to the row items where the value needs to be aggregated.

Sharing the sample data below:

Input table

```
row_number | row_name       |value   |  row_total_into |
--------------------------------------------------------
1051       |property tax    | Null   |1057             |
1052       |property_1 tax  | 25     |1057             |
1053       |property_2 tax  | 20     |1057             |
1054       |property_3 tax  |35      |1057             |
1055       |property_4 tax  |40      |1057             |
1056       |property_5 tax  |45      |1057             |
1057       |total prop tax  |Null    |1064             |
1058       |income tax      |Null    |1063             |
1059       |income_1 tax    |28      |1063             |
1060       |income_2 tax    |31      |1063             |
1061       |income_3 tax    |45      |1063             |
1062       |income_4 tax    |22      |1063             |
1063       |total income tax|Null    |1064             |
1064       |Overall tax     |Null    | 0               |
```

[image: Input table]

The required table will be in this format:

Output table

```
row_number  | row_name      |value  |row_total_into |Aggregate |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1051        |property tax   |Null   |1057           |Null      |   
1052        |property_1 tax |25     |1057           |25        |
1053        |property_2 tax |20     |1057           |20        |
1054        |property_3 tax |35     |1057           |35        |
1055        |property_4 tax |40     |1057           |40        |
1056        |property_5 tax |45     |1057           |45        |
1057        |total prop tax |Null   |1064           |165       |
1058        |income tax     |Null   |1063           |Null      |
1059        |income_1 tax   |28     |1063           |28        |
1060        |income_2 tax   |31     |1063           |31        |
1061        |income_3 tax   |45     |1063           |45        |
1062        |income_4 tax   |22     |1063           |22        |
1063        |total inc tax  |Null   |1064           |126       |
1064        |Overall tax    |Null   |0              |291       |
```

[image: Output table]

We need to get the aggregate column, where multiple levels of column 'row_value' are aggregated with the relationship established from row_total_into. I am not able to think of an approach that can help us get the aggregates. Any suggestions on how to approach this question (in terms of logic, code or any specific function) would be really helpful!

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are 2 completely different RDBMS, what one are you *really* using. What is your question here, I don't see a clear problem or question statement apart from "any suggestions?" which really isn't a question.

Comment: We are using Microsoft SQL server and Snowflake db, solution in any language will do, but I am expecting reference to a specific form of logic, or code. Will change the edits, apologies for the confusion

Comment: The goal is to get the aggregation in specific rows based on the ids mentioned in the row_total_into column. Please check the images attached for more clarity on how the output will be generated. If the Question is still not clear, will add more information

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This is a complicated problem.  In theory, you could have any number of levels of aggregation.  And that would require recursive CTEs or some method for looping.

If I assume the following:

- There are only two levels.  The subtotals and the final total.
- The final total is the total of all rows.

Then one approach basically uses a subquery to calculate the subtotals and overall total:

```
select t.*,
       (case when tt.row_total_into is null then t.value
             else coalesce(tt.value, tt.total_value)
        end) as aggregated
from t left join
     (select row_total_into, sum(value) as value,
             sum(sum(value)) over () as total_value
      from t
      group by row_total_into
     ) tt
     on tt.row_total_into = t.row_number
```

Comment: Actually, there are multiple levels... we have almost 10,000+ rows to work with and around 5-6 levels. Can you suggest a scalable solution? Would be really helpful :)

Comment: @Avinash1419 . . . This question is answered.  Can you ask a *new* question?  Providing some sample data in a db<>fiddle would be helpful, as would an appropriate database tag.  The answer here is standard SQL.  Your more complex question may require bespoke functionality.

Comment: Sure, will close this question thread and prepare a more detailed query